# New column showing day of the week from Date in R

Tags: r

This is my second day using R can anyone kindly tell me how to make a new column showing day of the week from an existing column which contains the dates.

my dates are in the format `%d/%m/%y`

I have used the following but it only shows for one day, I want it to show the whole column of dates

```
discount$day_of_week <-wday(as.Date('16-08-2012','%d-%m-%Y'), label=TRUE)
```

Can someone please kindly assist me?

Comment: Type `?weekdays` in your console.

Comment: Thanks It worked

Answer (score 0):

example of what you might want:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, date = seq(Sys.Date(), length.out = 5, by = 1))
df$day_name <-weekdays(df$date)
df
#   id       date day_name
# 1  1 2017-09-28 Thursday
# 2  2 2017-09-29   Friday
# 3  3 2017-09-30 Saturday
# 4  4 2017-10-01   Sunday
# 5  5 2017-10-02   Monday
```